# Pyqt5. Running string and clock

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a form with to labels (clock on the top and running string on the bottom). I added linker_by_grid to form (so that all components can proportional resize when form resize).
When I run project, every seconds text in running string is twitching. If I delete linker_by_grid from form, everything is OK, but all components not autoresizing to form.

Code from QtDesigner:

````
    class Ui_Form(object):
        def setupUi(self, Form):
            Form.setObjectName("Form")
            Form.resize(498, 299)
            self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
            self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 479, 281))
            self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(15)
            self.label_2.setFont(font)
            self.label_2.setText("")
            self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
            self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(15)
            self.label.setFont(font)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

            self.retranslateUi(Form)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        def retranslateUi(self, Form):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
            self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Running string ... "))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(Form)
        Form.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_()) ```


main file:

    ``` from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
    import sys
    import untitled


    class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Widget, self).__init__()
            self.ui = untitled.Ui_Form()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

            self.x = 477
            self.y = self.height() - 30
            self.ui.label.move(self.x, self.y)

            self.timer = QTimer(self)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move_label_left)
            self.timer.start(100)

            self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
            self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.show_clock)
            self.timer2.start(1000)

        def move_label_left(self):
            if self.x == -477:
                self.x = 477
                self.x -= 2
                self.ui.label.move(self.x, self.height() - 30)
            else:
                self.x -= 2
                self.ui.label.move(self.x, self.height() - 30)

        def show_clock(self):
            time = QTime.currentTime()
            text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
            self.ui.label_2.setText(text)


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `label` from the `layout`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime

#import untitled

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(500, 350)      #(498, 299)

#        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
#        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 479, 281))
#        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)     #(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 50)   # + 50
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)                 #(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)       #(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

#        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
#        font = QtGui.QFont()
#        font.setPointSize(15)
#        self.label.setFont(font)
#        self.label.setObjectName("label")
#        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
#        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Running string ... "))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True) # +
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) # +

        self.labelMove = QtWidgets.QLabel("Running string ... ", self)  # +
        font = QtGui.QFont()                                            # +
        font.setPointSize(15)                                           # +
        self.labelMove.setFont(font)                                    # +

        self.x = self.width() #477
        self.y = self.height() - 30 
        self.labelMove.move(self.x, self.y)               

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move_label_left)
        self.timer.start(15)                                 # 100

        self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.show_clock)
        self.timer2.start(1000)

    def move_label_left(self):
        if self.x <= -150:                                   # 477
            self.x = self.width()                            # 477
            self.x -= 1
            self.labelMove.move(self.x, self.height() - 30)
        else:
            self.x -= 1
            self.labelMove.move(self.x, self.height() - 30)
        self.labelMove.adjustSize()                           # +++

    def show_clock(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.ui.label_2.setText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Great !!! What kind between: self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form) self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget) and it: self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form) ?

Comment: So I see using QtDesigner is a very hard method to construct project ...

Comment: @ВладимирМещеряков  Sorry, does my example work for you? Is that something you need or is something wrong?

Comment: @ВладимирМещеряков   If my answer helped you, do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: I already did it, but: "votes cast by those with less then 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @ВладимирМещеряков   If  you do not know how to do it then review the here https://stackoverflow.com/tour , that is the best way to thank.